# emph: how to change the color only if two words follow each other?

Tags: color, listings, emphasis

I would like to know whether it is possible to give a different color for a string of multiple words. I would like to use dark blue for "proc catalog" and default blue for "catalog". Plese find the code below with the expected output.

[image]

```
proc catalog catalog=work.formats;
    contents;
    run;
quit;


\lstnewenvironment{sasproccatalog}{%
\lstset{%
    basicstyle      =\small\ttfamily,%
    language        =SAS,%
    keywords        ={},%
    keywordstyle    =\color{sasblue}\ttfamily\small,%
    commentstyle    =\color{sascomment},%  
    morecomment     =[f]{*},%
    morecomment     =[s]{/*}{*/},%
    morecomment     =[n]{/*}{*/},%
    escapechar      =|,%
    escapeinside    ={(*@}{@*)},
    stringstyle     =\color{sasviolet},%
    showstringspaces=false,%
    keepspaces      =true,%
    sensitive       =false,%
    emph            =[1]{run,{proc catalog},quit}, %
    emphstyle       =[1]\color{sasdarkblue}\textbf, %
    emph            =[2]{catalog,contents},%
    emphstyle       =[2]\color{sasblue}, %
    upquote         =true,%
    literate        ={à}{{\`a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1  {è}{{\`e}}1,%
    otherkeywords={},%
    alsoother={.}%
}
}{}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) you might want to change the title of your question to something like: `listings: how to change the color only if two words follow each other?`, as it sits now it is rather confusing in relation to actually being a listigns question. (3) On this site, it is always a good idea to post a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is, instead of posting a sniplet and the people guess the rest.

Comment: Please also modify your code to a [complete but minimal document](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). People will be more eager to help if they don't need to find a way to make your sample compilable before they can start working on the actual issue.